# Java JTable - Transparence with Nimbus/System L&F

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I have this JTable:

```
    List<MyTuple> l= new ArrayList<>();
    l.add(new Element(1,"One"));
    l.add(new Element(2,"Two"));
    l.add(new Element(3,"Three"));
    l.add(new Element(4,"Four"));
    l.add(new Element(5,"Five"));
    l.add(new Element(6,"Six"));
    l.add(new Element(7,"Seven"));

    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
    pane.setOpaque(false);
    pane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    pane.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    pane.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    pane.setBounds(3, 101, 707, 297);

    MyTableModel tm=new MyTableModel(l);
    table = new MyTable(tm);
    table.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    table.setOpaque(false);
    //table.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    table.getTableHeader().setOpaque(true);
    table.getTableHeader().setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
    table.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    table.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(false);
    table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    pane.setViewportView(table);
    pane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    table.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
    table.setShowGrid(true);
    getContentPane().add(pane);
```

MyTuple, MyTable and MyTableModel classes don't set any custom rendering.

This is how my table looks like under System L&F (which I really like):

[image: System LooksAndFeels]

This is how my table looks like under Nimbus L&F (note the added big rectangle):

[image: Nimbus LooksAndFeels]

I want my table to look like the one with System L&F.
The problem is that if I set one L&F like I want, the other gets ugly, I want a sort of "compatibility", is there a way to do so?

Maybe using the **UIManager.put()** method?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the border around the `viewport` of the `scrollpane`. Possible solutions:

- `pane.setViewportBorder(null);`
- `pane.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());`
- `pane.setViewportBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));`

Note that `pane.getViewport().setBorder(...)` will not work, because a `JViewport` doesn't actually have a border, `setViewportBorder` just draws a border *around* the viewport. ([Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29))

To make the table header transparent:

```
pane.setColumnHeader(new JViewport());
pane.getColumnHeader().setOpaque(false);

table.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! it works now... But what if i would like to make the header also transparent? i tried this: but with System L&F doesn't work: table.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0)); table.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);

Comment: No need to set the background color when using setOpaque( false ).

Comment: @LuxxMiner
The edit you did works on nimbus, but not on System L&F

Comment: @camickr
i Tried, but on Nimbus, if i don't set the background to Color(0,0,0,0), it won't disappear...